# How do I remove filtered data from a spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel, range

Just something I been working on has been bugging me and I can't help think someone else will point me to a simple solution.

Part of a program I am writing involves the following:

I have a C# program that applies a series of filters to a spreadsheet using autosort. The data that has been sorted I want to remove, currently it kind of does this use specialcells but I think my method isn't brilliant.

Before removing data I get rid of the first row which is my headings as to not include this in the delete. However this can cause an issue, If i remove the headings and the filtered data actually returned no more that 0 rows then when I call my specialcell to delete it will flag up some kind of error stating there is no range.
Whats the best solution to this, ideally I could grab the filtered range and check if the data has more than 1 row but the properties I been trying such as rows.count is flagging up the wrong sort of data.
Here is a simplified version of my code

```
Excel.Range AllRange = mySheet.UsedRange;
Excel.Range filtered = AllRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

if (//SOME SORT OF COUNT SHOULD GO HERE IM GUESSING > 1)
{
 mySheet.Rows.EntireRow[1].Hidden = true;
 filtered = mySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

filtered.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
mySheet.Rows.EntireRow[1].Hidden = false;       
}
```

Something like that, I hope that helps. Thanks for any advice you can give on the matter.

Comment: Could you please verify that the code in your question is the way it should be? The layout suggests that some curly bracket is missing or in the wrong place, making your question unclear.

Comment: Aww the curly bracket didn't make it into my code snippet. Ok I think I figured it out and i'm going to provide a solution for those who may have same issue later.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works. Basically you want to take in the `Areas.Count`.

```
Excel.Range AllRange = mySheet.UsedRange;
Excel.Range filtered = AllRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

long colstuff = filtered.Areas.Count;

if (colstuff > 1)
{
  mySheet.Rows.EntireRow[1].Hidden = true;
  filtered = mySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

  filtered.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
  mySheet.Rows.EntireRow[1].Hidden = false;   
}
```